# postmark mail provider says. mails "In queue" ?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail, postmark

I am currently working on postmark mail provider. it was working for me good. but now it is not working. it says " in queue. This email uses a Postmark Template, but has not yet been rendered by our system. Please check again shortly." please explain me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a developer on Postmark. When you're using a Postmark Template, we need to take the template model you submit, construct HTML and Text from it, and then send it through our normal sending pipeline. This typically happens so fast that you'll rarely see the "In Queue" status, if you're seeing this frequently, you should contact support via https://support.postmarkapp.com and we can provide more specific help for your case.